# Схема таблицы для сервиса, работающего с файлами

Tags: sql, база-данных, symfony, symfony3

Какая схема больше всего подойдёт для этого сервиса, если необходимо сохранять:

1. Название файла
2. Время создания
3. Объект(идентификатор записи в таблице), к которому этот файл относится

Сейчас используется следующая схема:

- id
- name
- entity_class_name
- entity_record_id

Подойдёт ли такая схема? Есть ли у неё какие-то недостатки?

Comment: "Время создания" не хватает в схеме

Comment: Да, забыл добавить это поле в список.
А хранить в ОДНОЙ таблице название классов(entity_class_name)  и ссылаться на запись в таблице(entity_record_id)  - хорошая практика?
Или лучше отдельные таблички создавать для каждой сущности?

Comment: я бы использовал [такой](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) подход